# How do variables equal in distribution interact?

Tags: distributions, variance, covariance

I have variables x and y that are equal in distribution. I want to find var(X-Y). This equals var(X)+var(Y)-2cov(X,Y). Am I correct in concluding that this equals 2var(X)-2var(X) which is 0? It just seemed strange to me.

Comment: "Equal in distribution" is a bit vague. If you mean $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, then your statement is incorrect. For example, let $X\sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y=-X$. Both $X$ and $Y$ are distributed $N(0,1)$, but $\text{var}(X-Y) = \text{var}(2X) = 4$.

Comment: No equal in distribution is not the same as equal. cov(X,Y) could be 0 or some non-zero value.  If it is 0 then var(X,Y) is 2 var(X). If covariance is not 0 the var(X-Y) is not necessarily 0.

Comment: Does the variance of Y equal the variance of X though?

Comment: Yes if X and Y are equal in distribution all the moments including the variance are the same for X and Y.

Comment: @MichaelChernick but the cov(x,y) doesn't equal the variance of X?

Comment: Right, that is why you don't get 0 for the var(X-Y). In Jirapat's example cov(X,Y)= 2 var(X).

Comment: So E(XY) also would not equal E(X^2)?

Comment: Not in general.